# How do I close fs.createWriteStream?

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to use the node module [vtt2srt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vtt-to-srt) to convert a VTT string to SRT file and save the output. It works once, and my subtitles are saved correctly,  but if I hit the endpoint a second time node crashes with this error:

```
Error: write after end
at writeAfterEnd
```

I have tried all combinations of .close .on('close')

I send a unique vid and the VTT data from the frontend

```
router.post('/downloadsubs', function(req,res,next) {
    var vttObj = webvtt.compile(req.body.data);

    fs.unlink(__dirname + '/../static/videos/'+req.body.vid+'/subtitles.srt', function(){
        srtStream.write(vttObj);
        var writestream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/../static/videos/'+req.body.vid+'/subtitles.srt')
        srtStream.end()
        srtStream.pipe(writestream)
        res.send(req.body.vid);
    }) 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out what my problem was, I hope it can be useful to someone else one day.

Previously I was requiring my module at the head of my router file:

```
const vtt2srt = require('node-vtt-to-srt');
const srtStream = vtt2srt();

router.post('/downloadsubs', function(req,res,next) {
    var vttObj = webvtt.compile(req.body.data);

    fs.unlink(__dirname + '/../static/videos/'+req.body.vid+'/subtitles.srt', function(){
        srtStream.write(vttObj);
        srtStream.end()
        var writestream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/../static/videos/'+req.body.vid+'/subtitles.srt');
        srtStream.pipe(writestream)
        writestream.on('finish', function () { res.send(req.body.vid) });
    })
})
```

Now, instead, I am creating a new srtStream in the router method:

```
const vtt2srt = require('node-vtt-to-srt');

router.post('/downloadsubs', function(req,res,next) {
    var srtStream = vtt2srt();
    var vttObj = webvtt.compile(req.body.data);

    fs.unlink(__dirname + '/../static/videos/'+req.body.vid+'/subtitles.srt', function(){
        srtStream.write(vttObj);
        srtStream.end()
        var writestream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/../static/videos/'+req.body.vid+'/subtitles.srt');
        srtStream.pipe(writestream)
        writestream.on('finish', function () { res.send(req.body.vid) });
    })
})
```

And it works.